# How to store polygon data in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created the table but I am not able to insert the polygon coordinates.

I tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
create table TEST5(
fig_name char(10),
fig_color char(10),
circle_loc circle,
polygon_loc polygon);

insert into TEST5(fig_name,fig_color,polygon_loc) 
values 
('poly' , 'red', POLYGON(POINT(9,3),POINT(9,9),POINT(5,9),POINT(5,3));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polygon definition is not correct, please try like this:

```
insert into TEST5
   (fig_name,fig_color,polygon_loc)
values ('poly' , 'red',  '((9,3),(9,9),(5,9),(5,3))');
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7nfuwnxp4Un3VBLTXDars3/0

Comment: Thanks, this is working.